# Python package not imported when executed through PHP

Tags: php, python, shell, spacy

I'm getting a import error for spacy when executing new_api.py through PHP. The python script gets successfully executed when run through the cmd

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$result = shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3 new_api.py "'.$input['queryResult']['queryText'].'" "'.$input['session'].'" 2>&1');
$output = json_encode(array(
            "source" => "source",
            "fulfillmentText" => $result
            ));
print_r($output);
?>
```

**Snippet Of Python Code**

```
import requests
import json
import sqlite3
import spacy
import sys

json_values = sys.argv[1:]
result = (home(json_values[0],json_values[1]))
print(result)
```

**The Output/Error Traceback**

> {"source":"source","fulfillmentText":"Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"new_api.py\", line 4, in \n    import spacy\nImportError: No module named 'spacy'\n"}

There's two version of python in the server. Both the versions has spacy installed in it and the python script is compatible with both versions.

**Things I've tried**

Tried using `exec()` and `shell_exec()` in php

Tried using `which python` path to execute the script

Tried running the script which both `python` and `python3`

The ImportError Still persists even after trying the combinations of the above steps. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the user of the server who execute the PHP script does not have enough permissions to access the module.

You can install the module as server user or use [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and I soleved it just a moment ago. This question is old, but I leave a note for people has same problem, and for me.

1. "printenv" on shell (your own user).
2. exec('printenv') from php (probably "apache" user).
3. Check difference between 1 and 2 results.

In my case, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/lib is needed (exist in 1 and not exist in 2). So I modified my code as follows:

> exec('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/lib python3 test_script.py 2>&1');